# Where in the C++ Standard does it say ::delete can change lvalues?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, lvalue, delete-operator

I ran into my first compiler that changes the lvalue passed to ::delete, but doesn't zero out the lvalue. That is the following is true:

```
 Foo * p = new Foo();
 Foo * q = p;
 assert(p != 0);
 assert(p == q);
 ::delete p;
 assert(p != q);
 assert(p != 0);
```

Note that p is not zero after the delete operation, and it has changed from it's old value. A coworker told me that this is not unusual in his experience having worked with some mainframe C++ compilers that would change p to 0xFFFFFFFF, as well as other compilers that would change p to 0.

Where in the C++ Standard does it say that a compiler is allowed to do this?

Searching through StackOverflow, I found this question: [Why doesn’t delete set the pointer to NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704466/why-doesnt-delete-set-the-pointer-to-null) which had an answer that referred to [Bjarne Stroustrup's response](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#delete-zero) that includes the statement:

> C++ explicitly allows an implementation of delete to zero out an lvalue operand, and I had hoped that implementations would do that, but that idea doesn't seem to have become popular with implementers.

I've read and re-read section 5.3.5 and 12.5 of the [final committee draft C++0x standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf), but I'm not seeing the "explicit" part. Am I just looking in the wrong sections of the standard? Or is there a chain of logic that is in the sections but I'm just not connecting together properly.

I don't have my copy of the Annotated C++ Reference Manual anymore. Was it in the ARM that a compiler could do this?

[Edit: Correcting the section reference from 3.5.3 to 5.3.5. I'm also adding an interesting paradox as a counterpoint to Henk's assertion that p is undefined after delete.]

There is an interesting paradox if p is initialized to null.

```
 Foo * p = 0;
 Foo * q = p;
 assert(p == 0);
 assert(p == q);
 ::delete p;
 assert(p == q);
 assert(p == 0);
```

In this case though, the behavior is well documented. When delete gets a null pointer, it is suppose to do nothing, so p remains unchanged.

Comment: Well, the ARM is neither here nor there. And let's forget about lvalues. Is your question "Can delete change its argument?".

Comment: Also, the standard is not big on saying what a compiler is allowed to do - it only specifies what it must and must not do. I can't see anything in e current standard that forbids the pointer value being changed.

Comment: I didn't phrase my question as "Can delete change its argument?" because I didn't want to get into how will a class declaring operator delete support changing its argument since it only take void*, not a void*& or void**.

Comment: Interesting - what if you declare p and q to be Foo * const? You should still be able to delete p, but does it's value still change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might not be so explicit. In 5.3.5/7 it says that the delete expression will call a deallocator function. Then in 3.7.3.2/4 it says that using a pointer that has been deallocated is undefined. Since the value of the pointer cannot be used after the deallocation, then whether the pointer keeps the value or the value is changed by the implementation does not make a difference.

5.3.5/7

> **The delete-expression will call a deallocation function** (3.7.3.2).

3.7.3.2/4

> If the argument given to a deallocation function in the standard library is a pointer that is not the null pointer value (4.10), the deallocation function shall deallocate the storage referenced by the pointer, render- ing invalid all pointers referring to any part of the deallocated storage. **The effect of using an invalid pointer value (including passing it to a deallocation function) is undefined**.

The references are from the current standard. In the upcoming standard 5.3.5/7 has been reworded:

C++0x FD 5.3.5/7

> If the value of the operand of the delete-expression is not a null pointer value, the delete-expression will call a deallocation function (3.7.4.2). Otherwise, it is unspecified whether the deallocation function will be called. [ Note: The deallocation function is called regardless of whether the destructor for the object or some element of the array throws an exception. — end note ]

Comment: OK, I take this as support for my point. If using an invalid pointer is undefined, a smart compiler is free to change pointers it knows to be invalid so that errors show up better. Fail fast, fail early.

Comment: @Henk: I completely agree with the compiler's intent to support the "fail fast, fail early" philosophy. It exposed a bug in code that has been shipping over almost 10 years now. We have a doubly linked list implementation which automatically updates the next, previous, and first node pointers in a node's destructor. The list's destructor was coded as "while (m_firstNode) delete m_firstNode;" Node destructor correctly updates m_firstNode, but compiler overwrites m_firstNode after destructor call with a non-zero value. Kaboom! If it was explicit, original code would have been different.

Comment: @Ants: interesting. This takes it to the edge, adding aliasing to the mix.

Comment: I don't think I believe this any more. A variable is *not* a value, and the standard says that the effect of using an invalid pointer value is undefined, not that the effect of using the variable is undefined. You can examine the variable without using its value (for example by aliasing with `unsigned char*` and comparing the bytes that it contained before and after the delete), and nothing quoted here says that the result of that is undefined. So IMO the standard does need to state that the variable's value can change in order for the implementation to be allowed to change it.