# delete does not assign 0 to the pointer

Tags: c++, c

In C or C++ when we delete some pointer, it only frees the memory but does not set the pointer to 0. Since we can not check the validity of a pointer, it would have been easier for the programmer to check the nullness of the pointer if the pointer is set to 0 after freeing the memory.

I was just wondering why 'delete' is implemented only to free the memory.

Comment: Just set it to NULL after deleting it.

Comment: As an aside, a lot of people make it a coding standard that immediately after you delete something, you manually set the pointer to 0.

Comment: delete setting the pointer to NULL would give a false sense of safety, there may very well be other pointers that point to the same memory block.

Comment: To add to the point @JoachimIsaksson makes, a good example of this is if the `delete` is done in a function and you don't pass the pointer as a reference or double-pointer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704466/why-doesnt-delete-set-the-pointer-to-null

Answer (score 4):

> “Since we can not check the validity of a pointer, it would have been easier for the programmer to check the nullness of the pointer if the pointer is set to 0 after freeing the memory.”

Checking for nullvalue is likely to hide bugs while increasing the code size and complexity, plus giving a false sense of security. There is no guarantee that the pointer value (before nulling) hasn't been copied elsewhere. Also, this prevents delete by value, which is a major annoyance with libraries (such as OpenCV) that, misguided, offer nulling delete operations.

Instead of such counter-productive practice, use techniques that ensure proper cleanup and prevent invalid pointers, such as using appropriate smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks Cheers and hth. - Alf, "There is no guarantee that the pointer value (before nulling) hasn't been copied elsewhere" -- This answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Because, in C++, it (almost) all about performance. You don't want the compiler to add code, you don't need. You don't want your program to do things, that you haven't added them in your code.

If you're sure, that on one will check/reuse this pointer, there's no need for annulling. One instruction less.

Also, if deleting a pointer, sets it to `NULL`, what will happen with the other pointers, that point to the already deleted memory? They will not be annulled. This could lead to bad things.

Just assign `NULL`, if you need it.

Comment: I regard this as being a good answer. That in C++ the compiler shouldn't do things for you that have a cost, if you might not need the action AND you can implement it yourself.

My deletes are almost always in the destructor of a class, so the pointer isn't going to exist shortly afterwards anyway so why would I want to pay the few nanoseconds cost of a useless assignment. It's easy enough to write a "safeDelete" template function if you want it to do that and call it instead of delete

Comment: @JohnB - my point, exactly :)

Comment: YEs, just agreeing. Unnecessarily :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need: Since you only `delete` in the destructor of your SBRM wrapper class, there's nothing else that could possibly access the pointer afterwards:

```
template <typename T> struct MyPtr
{
     template <typename ...Args> MyPtr(Args &&... args)
     : p(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
     {   }

     ~MyPtr()
     {
         delete p;   // done! who cares what `p` is now.
     }

     MyPtr(MyPtr const &) = delete;
     MyPtr & operator=(MyPtr const &) = delete;

     T * operator->() { return p; }

private:
     T * p;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on SBRM? A google returns nothing obvious.

Comment: Just call destructor twice :)

Comment: @cmh it's a fancy alternative name for RAII. Stands for Scope-Based Resource Management.

Comment: Thanks, would be good if the full def. was in the question for those that haven't seen it before.

Comment: @cmh: It's "scope-based resource management", a core C++ idiom. It is sometimes colloquially referred to as "RAII" ("resource acquisition is initialization") in the literature. It boils down to making *all* resources local by use of automatic, scoped variables. C++ provides "magic `goto`s" by means of destructors, and those allow you to write control flow with multiple exits with ease. "Never have to touch anything more than once", if you will.

Answer (score 0):

It would not make anything safer, even if `delete` assigned NULL to the pointer. Since multiple pointers can point to the same memory address and assigning NULL to one of these will not make others NULL as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a const pointer variable. Setting it to NULL is not possible, Only setting mutable pointer variables to NULL after delete seems somewhat inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you might want to do pointer arithmetic after delete for efficiency reasons:

```
const int SIZE = 5;
MyObject* foo[SIZE];
// ... initialize foo with new MyObjects...
for (MyObject* i = &foo[0], end = &foo[0] + SIZE; i < end; ++i)
{
    delete i;
}
```

Comment: I don't see this as a compelling reason, at least not with this example: #1 there are far better alternatives (an array of `std::unique_ptr`, `boost::scoped_ptr`, or even `std::auto_ptr` would be better) and #2 it is highly unlikely the pointer arithmetic will generate more efficient code than a loop through indices instead of pointers.

Comment: @r_martinho_fernandes Agreed, there are much better ways to do it now.  C++ didn't always have smart pointers readily available though.  As to point #2, yes it's unlikely, but C++ at least in the original implementation always tried to leave that sort of optimization available.