# If there are two pointers to the same data structure, and one is deleted, How do you check that the other one exists?

Tags: c++

This is the example code:

```
Node *n1 = new Node();
Node *n2 = new Node();
Node *n3 = new Node();

qWarning() << "Setting node names";
n1->setName("N1");
n2->setName("N3");
n3->setName("N3");

qWarning() << "Creating list";
QList<Node*> list;

list << n1 << n2 << n3;

qWarning() << "List iteration:";
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    qWarning() << "Node:" << list.at(i)->getName();
}

if (n1 != NULL){
    qWarning() << "N1 EXISTS";
}
else{
    qWarning() << "N1 DOES NOT EXIST";
}

qWarning() << "Clearing list, CLEARING EVERYTHING";
//list.clear();

while (list.size() > 0){
    Node *n = list.first();
    list.removeFirst();
    delete n;
}

qWarning() << "Accessing nodes";

if (n1 != NULL){
    qWarning() << "N1 EXISTS";
}
else{
    qWarning() << "N1 DOES NOT EXIST";
}
```

The problem is that both times the printed output is `N1 EXISTS`. However, clearly, If I try to access `n1` after the accessing nodes message, the program will crash. How can I check that the data structure to which `n1` points, actually exists?

Comment: You can't - you have so called *dangling pointers*. Accessing the element they point to invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: This is why you use smart pointers.  They can actually express ownership and the lifetime can be queried.

Comment: Ok. So the only way to prevent this is to make sure that this situation, doesn't happen. Correct?

Comment: You could explicitly set it to `nullptr` (or `NULL`) after deleting it.

Comment: It's your job to keep track of all references or pointer to an object and use / dereference them only if the object is alive.

Comment: The more you learn about programming, the more you'll be thankful that this _doesn't_ have the behavior you were expecting.

Comment: You should restructure your program so it is clear who owns what. Value semantics get you 99% there, and 99% of the rest of the time a `std::unique_ptr` will do and if that is still not enough `std::weak_ptr` + `std::shared_ptr` have exactly the feature you want, but you probably don't actually need it.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1930459/c-delete-it-deletes-my-objects-but-i-can-still-access-the-data

Comment: I guess this question gives you an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704466/why-doesnt-delete-set-the-pointer-to-null

Comment: I don't know what are smart pointers. Could you give me some info on it? Or a link with examples?

Comment: @aarelovich http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one

Comment: Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory

Answer (score 4):

Deleting a pointer doesn't deletes the pointer itself, it only frees up the memory that pointer was pointing to. Once you delete a pointer and then if you try to access the memory location that the pointer pointed to, it will invoke **undefined behavior**.