# Memory Leak Deleting a Node C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, memory-leaks, linked-list, nodes

Im trying to delete a node in a linked list in c++ but it keeps saying that _pending_tx is not nullptr after deleting transaction. Also valgrind says I have a memory leak and I can't figure it out

```
bool BankData::void_transaction(const size_t& customer_id, const size_t& timestamp) { 

bool var8 = false;

if (transaction_exists(customer_id, timestamp) == true)
{
    int blah3 = customerVector.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < blah3; i++)
    {
        if (customerVector.at(i)._customer_id == customer_id)
        {
            if (customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs != nullptr)
            {
                CSE250::dTransactionNode *temp = customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs;
                while (temp->_tx._timestamp != timestamp)
                {
                    temp = temp->_next;
                    if ((temp->_next == nullptr) && (temp->_tx._timestamp != timestamp))
                    {
                        var8 = false;
                    }
                }
                if (temp->_tx._timestamp == timestamp)
                {
                    if ((temp->_prev == nullptr) && (temp->_next == nullptr))         //head and only node
                    {
                        delete  customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs = nullptr; //after i delete the head and only node i reset it to a nullptr
                        var8 = true;
                    }
                    else if ((temp->_prev == nullptr) && (temp->_next != nullptr))     //head
                    {
                        temp = customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs->_next;
                        delete  customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs = temp;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs->_prev = nullptr;
                        var8 = true;
                    }
                    else if ((temp->_prev != nullptr) && (temp->_next == nullptr))    //tail
                    {
                        temp = customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs->_prev;
                        delete  customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs = temp;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs->_next = nullptr;
                        var8 = true;
                    }
                    else                                                              //middle node
                    {
                        temp = customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs->_next;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs->_next->_prev = customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs->_prev;
                        delete  customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs = temp;
                        //temp->_prev->_next = temp->_next;
                        //temp->_next->_prev = temp->_prev;
                        //temp = nullptr;
                        //delete temp;
                        var8 = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return var8;
```

This is the node struct that I'm trying to delete:

```
namespace CSE250 {
struct dTransactionNode;}

struct CSE250::dTransactionNode {
Transaction _tx;

dTransactionNode* _prev;

dTransactionNode* _next;

dTransactionNode(size_t time, double amount) : _tx(time, amount), _prev(nullptr), _next(nullptr) { }};
```

I also can't figure out why when i try to delete it, it will only delete the timestamp and not the timestamp and amount. so when I run my transaction exists function it still says part of the transaction exists.

[That's the valgrind message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxuAA.jpg)

[And those are the error messages I get that say its not pointing to a nullptr after the transaction has been voided even thoguh i set it manually to a null ptr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xCsV.jpg)

Comment: delete sets nothing to null pointer.

Comment: Use an appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: so would you say

temp = customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs;
customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs = nullptr;
delete temp:
?

Comment: No @MatthewKirshy, that would result in a memory leak, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you `delete` something, the pointer is not set to `nullptr` automatically. It's the programmers duty to do so. Read more in [Why doesn't delete set the pointer to NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704466/why-doesnt-delete-set-the-pointer-to-null)

When you set a pointer to null, it doesn't delete the memory. If you do so, before you call `delete`, then you will create a memory leak, if you don't delete the memory with another pointer that refers to it.

Smart pointers can be used, which do the trick for you.

Comment: right, doesnt the second line take care of that?


 delete  customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs;
                        customerVector.at(i)._pending_txs = nullptr; //after i delete the head and only node i reset it to a nullptr
                        var8 = true;

Comment: Yes @MatthewKirshy.

Comment: Thats what I did and i still get the memory leak

Comment: That means @MatthewKirshy, that you don't delete your nodes correctly. Remember, you should `delete` *exactly as many* nodes as you created with `new`.